# How set alarm using date picker and time picker and saved in sqlite database in android

Tags: android, android-alarms

Can anyone help me in this problem. well what i need to do is set a date and time for an alarm notification and store it in sqlite database to be shown in a recyclerview.

now my problem is that i do not know how to set the alarm. i have my date picker and timepicker working but i do not know how to set the alarm, so can anyone show me how to set it?

**Heres my code**

```
    public class set_events extends AppCompatActivity {
    Register_pet_database myDB;
    Spinner event_pet;
    Button btn_setevent;
    eventsAdapter adapter;
    EditText datepicker, time, note;
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    Calendar myCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    TextView tf1, tf2, tf3,tf4;
    ArrayList<events_counter> arrayList= new ArrayList<>();
    events_counter  alert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_events);
        myDB=new Register_pet_database(this);
        btn_setevent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_seteventnow);
        datepicker = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.takedate);
        time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.taketime);
        note = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mynote);
        event_pet=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.eventlist);
        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.set_toolbar_events);
        tf1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.setevents);
        tf2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.setdates);
        tf3=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.settimes);
        tf4=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.setnotes);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        AddEvent();
        Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/agency-fb.ttf");
        tf1.setTypeface(font);
        Typeface font1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/agency-fb.ttf");
        tf2.setTypeface(font1);
        Typeface font2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/agency-fb.ttf");
        tf3.setTypeface(font2);
        Typeface font3 = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/agency-fb.ttf");
        tf4.setTypeface(font3);

          final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date= new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                    myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                    updateLabel();
                }
            };
        datepicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DatePickerDialog(set_events.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });
        time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar currentTime= Calendar.getInstance();
                final int hour = currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                final int minute = currentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                mTimePicker= new TimePickerDialog(set_events.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                        if(hourOfDay<12 && hourOfDay >=0){
                            time.setText( hourOfDay + ":" + minute+" AM");
                        }
                        else{
                            hourOfDay-=12;
                            if(hourOfDay==0){
                                hourOfDay=12;
                            }
                            time.setText( hourOfDay + ":" + minute+" PM");
                        }

                    }
                },hour,minute,true);
                mTimePicker.show();
            }
        });
        final ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.events, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        event_pet.setAdapter(adapter);
        event_pet.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if(position==0){
                    note.setText("Im going to feed my pet now");
                }
                if(position==1){
                    note.setText("Im going to take my pet to the veterinarian!");
                }
                if(position==2){
                    note.setText("Im going to take my pet for a walk !");
                }
                if(position==3){
                    note.setText("Im going to take my pet to the groomers !");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void updateLabel() {
        String myFormat = "MM/dd/yy"; //In which you need put here
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat);
        datepicker.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }

private void AddEvent(){
    btn_setevent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
            adapter=new eventsAdapter(set_events.this,arrayList);
            alert= new events_counter();
            alert.setEvent_name(event_pet.getSelectedItem().toString());
            alert.setEvent_date(datepicker.getText().toString());
            alert.setEvent_time(time.getText().toString());
            alert.setEvent_note(note.getText().toString());
            Boolean insertEvent=myDB.insertDataToEvent(alert);
            try{
                if (insertEvent = true) {
                    adapter.add(alert);
                    Toast.makeText(set_events.this, "Your event has been Registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(set_events.this, eventlist.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(set_events.this, "Your event has not been Registerd", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(set_events.this, eventlist.class);
        intent.putExtra("Tab", 1);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of alarm? Do you want that alarm goes off when your app isn't running? what about when mobile device reboots?

Comment: no i want alarm that even when the device is off it will turn on that kind of alarm

Comment: you should use alarmmanager. get help from [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) or [this](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) to set an alarm. if you get in trouble ask me.

Comment: well my problem is that i have a edit when click will popup date and time picker now that i want to get the date and time set but i do not now how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you set your time and date in your `Calendar` variable like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0 );
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
```

then set your alarm like this:

```
alarmmgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                calendar, INTERVAL, pendingintent);
```